# Increase variable value through charAt()

Tags: java

I'm new for Java,and I want to know can we increase the variable value through charAt() in java as below.

```
public class CheckPalindrome{
public static boolean isPalindrome(String text) {

int length = text.length();
int forward = 0;
int backward = length - 1;
while (backward > forward) {
    char forwardChar = text.charAt(forward++);
    char backwardChar = text.charAt(backward--);
    if (forwardChar != backwardChar)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
     System.out.println (isPalindrome("level"));
   }
}
```

I want to know what is happening below code line..

```
char forwardChar = text.charAt(forward++);
```

Comment: `String` is immutable, so no. Create a new string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The value of which variable?

Comment: @Lankani Can you explain more what you're doing here ? It's unclear right now... Why do you want to do that ? What is `text` ? what is representing `forward` ? what do you expect `forwardChar` to be ?

Comment: Your question is simply unclear. Are you asking how to loop through something that can be looped on?

Comment: just edit my question

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, so no you can't do that. You need to create a new string (e.g. with [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))) and combine the results:

```
String text = "ABCCEFG";

char midCharacter = text.charAt(3);
midCharacter++;

String output = text.substring(0, 3) + midCharacter + text.substring(4);
```

Output:

> ABCDEFG

Comment: I really hope that this is what the question is asking :D have an optimistic upvote.